# Is there a way to track changes as one would in MS Word when collaborating with someone on code?

Tags: version-control

I am working with someone abroad on a project and I'm having trouble keeping track of all the changes they make and vice versa. Is there a software or code editor that will keep track of changes allowing other users to see what's changed?

Comment: We had a programmer that would only make changes in word and then upload to the mainframe.  You could do that.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using [source control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control)?
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/976132/what-is-a-good-free-source-control-solution) are some (free) options. There are many of those, just look it up..